# Permanent PATH setting Problem for Flutter

Tags: linux, ubuntu, flutter, terminal, path

I'm using Linux, flutter has been installed but there is a problem in setting permanent path
on `.bash_profile` I used this command `export PATH="$PATH:/home/anas/Documents/flutter/bin"`
and after saving this file I use command `source '/home/anas/.bash_profile'` again working fine
and now I'm able to run `flutter doctor` which is also fine

**But there is a main problem**
whenever I restart my terminal the path settings are changed and now I should run again `source '/home/anas/.bash_profile'` *otherwise* on `flutter doctor` it gives me error

> flutter: command not found

means my path is not set for permanent it only saves for temporary what should I do to resolve this issue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every shell has own configuration file.

`zsh` is searching `~/.zshrc` (and `/etc/zshrc`) file,

but `csh` is searching `~/.cshrc` (and `/etc/csh.cshrc`) file

To make it working for all of them you can add your stuff in to

```
~/.bashrc
```

Because it is evaluated everytime when you are starting any shell.

Comment: @MuhammadAnas would you upvote also as valuable response?